# Disable Spanner audit logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, logging, google-cloud-spanner

Running performance test against Spanner database I observed that Spanner produces tremendous number of audit logs that cost a lot (8x more that Spanner Nodes in my tests). Is there any possibility to disable Spanner audit logs? If not how can I reduce the cost of them?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this type of logs: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/audit-logging#enabling_audit_logging

System and admin logs cannot be disabled, but I would be surprised if your performance test would execute a large number of such operations. If they do, could you please share some more detail on what your performance test does?

Data access audit logs are disabled by default. If these have been enabled for your project, you can disable them again using these steps:

1. From the Google Cloud console, select IAM & Admin > Audit Logs: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/audit
2. Select your Cloud project, folder, or organization.
3. In the Data Access audit logs configuration table, select one or more Google Cloud services.
4. In the Log Types tab in the information panel, select the Data Access audit log types that you want to disable for your selected services.
5. Click Save.

Source:
https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/configure-data-access#config-console-disable

Comment: I've checked the logs and log name is `cloudaudit.googleapis.com/data_access`. Operations like Commit, ExecuteStreamingSql, etc are logged,  but what can I see in the audit logs configuration is that for my project Data Read and Data Write audit logs are disabled. But there is also a message: `You don't have permission to view inherited audit logs configuration data for one or more parent resources. Information below may be incomplete` therefore I will have to check this setting with my organization. Thank you for your help